# How to add a Google Doc link on an existing script

Tags: javascript

So I found this helpful template script to create an automating help desk workflow. User fills out the form and they automatically receive an email with the message "Thanks for submitting your issue. \n\nWe'll start " + "working on it as soon as possible.

```
function formSubmitReply(e) {
    var userEmail = e.values[3];
    MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail,
      "Help Desk Ticket",
      "Thanks for submitting your issue. \n\nWe'll start " +
      "working on it as soon as possible. \n\nHelp Desk",
      {name:"Help Desk"});
```

All I want to do is add clickable link to our procedure Google Doc page to the that message. I just learning the basics of scripting and just need a little jump start on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a clickable link like this:
function formSubmitReply(e) {
var userEmail = e.values[3];
MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail,
"Help Desk Ticket",
"Thanks for submitting your issue. \n\nWe'll start " +
"working on it as soon as possible. \n\nHelp Desk" +""+Click here+"",
{name:"Help Desk"});

Comment: It seems to break the script.

Comment: No, it will not. Actually, before "click here" text, i had appended anchor tag but due to some reason, it is not being displayed here. So, if you can try with anchor tag in your code, it will work.